# I can not get matplotlib to display the correct graph for my graphing script

Tags: python-2.7

a graph shows but it does not show the correct output that it is supposed to. I hope it is not the graph class,It would be helpful to get this to work.
I am trying to make a dynamic graphing script that can run complex graphing equations but i can't seem to get past simple equations

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
def drange(start,stop,step):
    r=start
    while r < stop:
        yield r
        r += step
class graph():
    def __init__(self):
        self.equation="x^2"
        self.slope=1
        self.Xshelf=30#max and min
        self.Yshelf=30
        self.lines=[]
    def run(self,v=False):
        adv=False
        self.lines=[]
        data=[[],[]]
        f=True
        print("caculateing...")
        for x in drange(-self.Xshelf-1,self.Xshelf,self.slope):
            x=x+1
            for y in drange(-self.Yshelf-1,self.Yshelf,self.slope):
                y=y+1
                try:
                    t=None
                    try:
                        t=eval(self.equation,{"x":x,"y":y,"t":t})
                    except Exception as e:
                        exec(self.equation,{"x":x,"y":y,"adv":t})
                    if v==True:
                        print(x,y)
                    if f==False and adv==True:
                        self.lines.append([data])
                        data=[[x],[y]]
                        f=True
                    else:
                        if t==True or t==None:
                            data[0].append(x)#x
                            data[1].append(y)#y
                            break
                        elif t!=False:
                            data[0].append(x)#x
                            data[1].append(t)#y
                            break
                except Exception as e:
                    if f:
                        print(e)
                    f=False
        self.lines.append(data)
        print("done")
    def render(self):
        fig=plt.figure()
        for line in self.lines:
            plt.plot(line[0],line[1])
            print line
        plt.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    i=graph()
    i.run(False)
    i.render()
```

Comment: Try to debug - you can install an IDE, like PyCharm and go through your code line by line and see where it breaks, or behaves differently than you expect. Than add that information here

Comment: i can try to debug the program, althogh it might be my use of `try:` command

Comment: also catch the exception